# How do I truncate the beginning of breadcrumbs in materializecss when they exceed the length of the screen to only leave the final breadcrumbs?

Tags: html, css, materialize, truncate, breadcrumbs

To be more descriptive on my issue, when the depth of the tree in my inventory system exceeds the X size of the screen, the breadcrumbs are cut off. I am fine with this behavior, although I want this to be truncated to only leave the deepest parts of the tree viewable, not the least deep.

If I have 20 items, and the screen can only show 10, I want to show the last 10 instead of the first 10.

If I have these breadcrumbs:
{hello > breadcrumbs > example > foobar > this > is > getting > full}
and it cuts off at foobar, I want it to show as many as it can going from the right backwards, which might be:

{example > foobar > this > is > getting > full}

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using a mix of `direction:rtl`, `overflow:hidden` & `whitespace:nowrap`, and a bit of the materialize grid:

```
 <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper container row">
        <div class="breadcrumb-wrapper col s12 m6">
          <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb"><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
          <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb">Second</a>
          <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb">Third</a>
          <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb">Fourth</a>
          <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb">Fifth</a>
          <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb">Sixth</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I've added in a `.row` to the nav-wrapper - this allows us to use the grid system. We need this to bring the breadcrumbs back to the left hand side of the page, because by setting `direction:rtl`, while we shift the content so that the right hand side is always visible, it is also right aligned.

The CSS:

```
.breadcrumb-wrapper {   
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    direction: rtl;
}

.breadcrumb:before {
    display: inline; 
}
```

This hides any breadcrumbs that spill outside of the col.

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/gOPGWWp

Comment: Hi, this works for the most part.
The only issue I'm having is that icons (from MaterializeCSS) are put on the right, not the left. Now I have the home icon all the way on the right.
Here's an example image: https://gyazo.com/83ecbbb7bf486bb43ab91dab80b9eb85

Comment: Working fine in the updated codepen, have you got a stray `right` class somewhere? https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/gOPGWWp. EDIT: Had to adjust the display property of the breadcrumb:before element, from inline-block to block.

Comment: Overlap on your codepen with the icon: https://gyazo.com/982fbb418b2cecf4579f196e54ad7167